# Multiple slideshows in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make multiple slideshows on my website, making use of some old w3schools code. The issue with their code is that it only allows a single slideshow per page which is not quite what i'm going for. To make it clear, I want to be able to have an infinite amount of slideshows per page but I don't want to copy and paste my code multiple times if possible

CSS:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container2 {
    position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    color: white;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    // Next/previous controls
    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    // Thumbnail image controls
    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
```

HTML:

```html
            <h3>Minigame Mania:</h3>
            <div class = "container2" >
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">1/3</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay1.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">2/3</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay2.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">3/3</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay3.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                <div class ="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay1.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay2.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay3.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Same Level Prototype info, description etc -->
            <h3>Same Level Prototype:</h3>
            <div class = "container2">
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">1/3</div>
                        <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay1.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">2/3</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay2.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div class ="mySlides">
                    <div class ="numberText">3/3</div>
                    <img src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay3.png" style="width: 100%">
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                <div class ="caption-container">
                    <p id="caption"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay1.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay2.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                    <div class ="column">
                        <img class ="demo cursor" src="assets/img/SameLevelPrototypeGameplay3.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Gameplay">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have tried a few methods such as adding gallery ID's but they weren't successful. I'm rather new to html, css and js so that's why i'm stumped on a problem that probably seems simple to some of you. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest using something other than "old w3schools code". Find a more modern script that does what you want. There are thousands of slideshow scripts out there (alternatively called "carousel" or "slider")...

Comment: I would recommend checking out [Bootstrap's Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). The page I linked shows how the HTML works, and requires very little JS.